# How to Handle a splited image in background thread?

Tags: html, image, css, css-grid

I have an LARGE image that needs to be a part of a site, of course this hits the performance. I got the idea to cut it up into pieces and stich the image together at load using a grid was my idea.

One tiny problem though... it has to be in the background.

Should I go the dreadful z-index way to fix this or is there a more beautiful solution? The image can be cut in any number of tiles.

Comment: Did you try something out so that we could get a clear layout of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Beware of words like "dreadful" and "beautiful", they can get your question closed as primarily opinion based. By the way, I'm not sure what cutting up a picture into parts and using lazy loading has to do with z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the [required browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) you could use multiple background images. Position them in their appropriate position in the background.

```css
html,
body,
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-image: 
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image1),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image2),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image3),
    url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image4);
  background-repeat: 
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat;
  background-position: 
    top left,
    top right,
    bottom left,
    bottom right;
  background-size: 
    51% 50%,
    50% 50%,
    51% 50%,
    50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The problem I got and have ignored since I posted the question, lots of other stuff to do, is that the background image is not tile-able, that is the problem I am facing.

Comment: In the question you said you had cut up the image? It would help if you could share the image so we know what we’re working with.